# I am looking to mouseover in javascript where the event is attached to a paragraph, but it will change the style of a different element

Tags: javascript, css, styles, addeventlistener, mouseover

I have 8 pics containing paragraphs all with the class .pic-link (i used the paragraph as the link because it's z-index has to remain the highest). There is a div underneath the pic which is orginally styled in css for a shaded effect, it's class is .shade..
I want to mouseover .pic-link but change .shade to make it's background = "white"...i think i can do this in css like this- .pic-link:hover:shade, but i want to know it for javascript.. this is my attempt

```
var shade = document.querySelector(".shade");
var pic = document.querySelectorAll(".pic- 
link");
for (var i = 0; i < pic.length; i++) {
pic[i].addEventListener("mouseover", 
function(event) {
        shade.style.background = "white";
    })
}
```

i know i will have to add mouseout, i'm just looking for the logic..my code will add the mouseover for every pic, but doesnt match the style change to the pic that's hovered over... i even tried selecting all .shade class and writing
shade[i].style.background = "white" but that is even less affective.
EDIT...HTML as followed...

```
<div class="single-pic-container"> 
                    <div class="shade"></div>
                    <img src="./images/mobile/image-deep-earth.jpg" alt="picture of earth" class="pic mobile-pic">
                    <img src="./images/desktop/image-deep-earth.jpg" alt="picture of earth" class="pic desktop-pic">
                    <a href="#" class="pic-link"><p>
                        Deep <br> earth
                    </p></a>   
                </div>
```

one image is set to dislpay = "none"; until media queries.
and the container div .single-pic-container is display = "grid", so i could easily overlay the paragraph.
Plus i'm practicing grid.

Comment: Please, show the HTML code, to demonstrate how are the HTML-tags positioned relative to each other.

Comment: Of course. I should have done that in the first place...I will amend the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `backgroundColor` instead of `background`:

```
const pics = document.querySelectorAll('.pic-link');

const mouseOverHandler = (e) => { // e - it's an event.
  // e.currentTarget - it's an access to an element-source of the event.
  const shade = e.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector('.shade');
  shade.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
};

const mouseOutHandler = (e) => {
  const shade = e.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector('.shade');
  shade.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'; // Set there background color as it was before
};

pics.forEach((pic) => {
  pic.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverHandler);
  pic.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutHandler);
});
```

If elements will be destroyed, you have to remove listeners, to avoid of memory leaks. So use as event listeners functions with names only. Because anonymous functions can not be removed in expression like `pic.removeEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { //... })`.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to change the style in css to use the backgroundcolor property, because i had an orginal linear gradient to override.   Also... i'm assuming = () => is just a different syntax for function. and i'm assuming the selecors e.currentTarget.parentNode are what ties the style change of shade to the specific event and forEach is a function that syphons through the pics array negating the need for the for loop. i will further investigate the literature.

Comment: Yes, you right. I've added comments to the code. And arrow function is not only new syntax, you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: quick update.. the linear gradient effect i have cannot be used on background -color... i've read linear gradient can only be used where images would be used, so to keep the effect i must continue to use background.